# udev - collect usb classes under one symlink

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I have 4-Port USB HUB with connected multiple USB-Devices with same/similar (one or more classes may be/may not be available) functionality where i want to collect device classes under one symlink directory with port/path identification

It should looks like:

```
/dev/usb_port0
└── tty*
└── hidraw*
└── sd*
└── ...

/dev/usb_port1
└── tty*
└── hidraw*
└── sd*
└── ...

 /dev/usb_port-n
└── tty*
└── hidraw*
└── sd*
└── ...
```

Device-A is connected to port 2 - hidraw class:

```
$ udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/hidraw0
  looking at device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2/1-1.4.2:1.3/0003:0D28:0204.0016/hidraw/hidraw0':
    KERNEL=="hidraw0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2/1-1.4.2:1.3/0003:0D28:0204.0016':
    KERNELS=="0003:0D28:0204.0016"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-generic"
    ATTRS{country}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2/1-1.4.2:1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4.2:1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ...

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ...
    ATTRS{product}=="DAPLink CMSIS-DAP"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ...
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub             "
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="VIA Labs, Inc.         "
```

Device-A is connected to port 2 - tty class:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/ttyACM0
    looking at device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2/1-1.4.2:1.1/tty/ttyACM0':
        KERNEL=="ttyACM0"
        SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
        DRIVER==""

      looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2/1-1.4.2:1.1':
        KERNELS=="1-1.4.2:1.1"
        SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
        DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
        ...

      looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2':
        KERNELS=="1-1.4.2"
        SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
        DRIVERS=="usb"
        ...
        ATTRS{product}=="DAPLink CMSIS-DAP"

      looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
        KERNELS=="1-1.4"
        SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
        DRIVERS=="usb"
        ...
        ATTRS{manufacturer}=="VIA Labs, Inc.         "
        ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub     

    "
```

My udev rule: /etc/udev/rules.d/90-port-2.rules

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="debug_rules"
DEVPATH!="*1-1.4.2", GOTO="debug_rules"

ACTION=="add", GROUP="usb", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="usbdev/%k-%n"

LABEL="debug_rules"
```

$ journalctl -f | grep usbdev says:

```
systemd-udevd[5608]: 1-1.4.2: /etc/udev/rules.d/90-port-2.rules:4 LINK 'usbdev/1-1.4.2-2'
systemd-udevd[5608]: 1-1.4.2: Creating symlink '/dev/usbdev/1-1.4.2-2' to '../bus/usb/001/029'
systemd-udevd[5612]: 1-1.4.2: Updating old name, '/dev/usbdev/1-1.4.2-2' no longer belonging to '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.2'
systemd-udevd[5612]: 1-1.4.2: No reference left, removing '/dev/usbdev/1-1.4.2-2'
```

Please, have you an idea of how to implement this method?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in udev manpage and debug logout i found answer.

My previous rule miss **bind** Action

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="debug_rules"
```

into

```
ACTION!="add|bind", GOTO="debug_rules"
```

also whole rule should looks:

```
KERNELS=="1-1.4.2:*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw|tty|scsi_generic", OWNER="ubuntu", GROUP="usb", SYMLINK+="usbport/2/%k", , MODE="0666", OPTIONS+="last_rule", GOTO="debug_rules"
```

and symlinks are (tree view)

```
/dev/usbport/
└── 2
    ├── hidraw0 -> ../../hidraw0
    ├── sg0 -> ../../sg0
    └── ttyACM0 -> ../../ttyACM0
```